# Why sometimes Bitmaps are the same objects?

Tags: java, android, matrix, bitmap

In my code I'm doing something like this:

```
public void doStuff() {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = decodeFileAndResize(captureFile);
    saveResizedAndCompressedBitmap(scaledBitmap);

    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = convertToRotatedBitmap(scaledBitmap);
    driverPhoto.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);

    if (rotatedBitmap != scaledBitmap) {
        scaledBitmap.recycle();
        scaledBitmap = null;
        System.gc();
    }
}

private Bitmap convertToRotatedBitmap(Bitmap scaledBitmap) throws IOException {
    ExifInterface exifInterface = new ExifInterface(getCaptureFilePath());
    int exifOrientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
    float orientationDegree = getRotationDegree(exifOrientation);
    Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
    rotateMatrix.postRotate(orientationDegree);

    return Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, true);
}
```

Everything working fine, but when I commenting `if (rotatedBitmap != scaledBitmap) {` I have an errors about using recycled Bitmap.

Is Android creates new Bitmap on every `Bitmap.createBitmap` call and how can I avoid comparison between bitmaps?

Comment: Since `createBitmap(..)` method you are using returns an immutable Bitmap, it's likely it is actually storing `scaledBitmap` as a member instead of creating a new Bitmap from scratch.

Comment: Actually, there's one if -clause within `createBitmap(...)` which returns same Bitmap as given as a parameter. Maybe your code hits this exact case making `scaledBitmap == rotatedBitmap`. [Bitmap.java](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/android-core/platform-frameworks-base/android/graphics/Bitmap.java.htm)

Comment: I think Your are doing something wrong here. The code line `rotatedBitmap != scaledBitmap` will give you true all the time.Because you are comparing two objects and those are not primitives.So two objects not equals each other.

Comment: If I will delete this line, my working bitmap can be recycled

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`createBitmap(Bitmap source, int x, int y, int width, int height, Matrix m, boolean filter)` **returns an immutable bitmap from subset of the source bitmap, transformed by the optional matrix.**

***Create BitMap method will return the same Bitmap method which is passed if all of the following condition satisfies***

- If your sourceBitmap is immutable and
- pixel starts from 0,0 x-y and
- the expected width and height is same as original width and height and
- matrix is null

In android source code something have been written like the following

```
if (!source.isMutable() && x == 0 && y == 0
                && width == source.getWidth() && height == source.getHeight()
                && (m == null || m.isIdentity())) {
            return source;
    }
```

**See the source code of BitMap.java from here**

http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java

or

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/graphics/Bitmap.java